# "git binary diffs are not supported" error using yocto

Tags: patch, yocto

I have one git repo where i maintain some binary files. Now i want to create patches of last few commits & integrate them in Yocto build.

I have created patches like

```
git format-patch -3 --binary
```

Now i have integrate these patches in Yocto recipe files. And Yocto gives below error while `git apply` in `do_patch()`

```
git binary diffs are not supported.
Patch xyz.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
```

Am i missing anything while creating binary patches here?

or

Is there any Yocto Hacks which i can do in my recipe file to handle with binary patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use this cmd with additional flag `--full-index`

`git format-patch -3 --full-index --binary`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch
--binary 
In addition to --full-index, output a binary diff that can be applied with git-apply.

Comment: This works with direct git apply commands. But still these patches does not work with Yocto !!

Comment: The possible reason is a different history of bin-files. So, are the Yocto bin-file and patched bin-file history are the same?

Comment: Yes patch history are same in both cases. Now i have forked do_patch() in recipe file & applied patches with git apply and those works fine. But with default do_patch() implementation its gives same error.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this with patches created using the yocto tooling (devtool update-recipe), and I do not want to change the way I create the patches.

By default yocto uses quilt to apply patches, I addressed the issue using git instead.

This can be configured by setting the [`PATCHTOOL`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PATCHTOOL) variable in the recipe:

```
PATCHTOOL = "git"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any Yocto Hacks which i can do in my recipe file to handle with binary patches?

When I deal with binary sources, I put the binary parts in a `.tar.gz`, add that to `SRC_URI` and then `cp` the bits I need to where I need them with a `do_install_append`.